# How to Github repository show on local machine?

Tags: git, github

How to fetch all repository from GitHub with Git Gui?

The goal is to clone the repos for a given GitHub user.

Comment: "all repository" as in, every repo on github?? or do you mean just on repo?

Comment: "all repository"  suppose i have git hub account and there is all my repository , i want to fetch all repository to local server with GUI then i edit them and re back to my git hub with GUI.?

Comment: how to see my clients project files in local computer with GUI (git)?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of a solution that would use only the GUI.

You could use the [GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/) to get the list of repo of a given user.
See "[List user repositories](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-user-repositories)"

This [gist gives a good example](https://gist.github.com/caniszczyk/3856584), using ruby:

```
curl -s https://api.github.com/users/<user>/repos?per_page=200 | ruby -rubygems -e 'require "json"; JSON.load(STDIN.read).each { |repo| %x[git clone #{repo["ssh_url"]} ]}'
```

Replace `<user>` with your GitHub user name.

For readability:

```
curl -s https://api.github.com/users/<user>/repos?per_page=200 | \
ruby -rubygems -e 'require "json"; JSON.load(STDIN.read).each { \
   |repo| %x[git clone #{repo["ssh_url"]} ]}'
```

Note that it doesn't handle pagination, which means that you only get your first 200 repos.